# "Many2many fields" error occurs when inheriting the model in Odoo

Tags: inheritance, module, model, field, odoo-16

I am trying a Students Module inherited from Contacts (Res.Partner), just to show My Student menu, not adding less. But when Active Module, this error "**TypeError: many2many fields my.students.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns**"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you shouldn t need to create a new many2many fields "channel_ids" in your myStudent-model, because this field is already existing in its inheriting model (res.partner)...
But, if you somehow really need to create a new many2many fields on the same co-model ("mail.channel"?) for a different purpose than the original one, the following explanation might help you to understand how to fix your error:

In case of two many2many fields created in the same (inherited-)model (res.partner) which relate to the same co-model (mail.channel), you have to define explicitly the name of the **relation** (corresponding to the join-Table in the postgre-Database) in the definition of your field.Many2many (for example: **relation="mail_channel_mystudents"**)

...to make it different from the **relation** name already existing in the Many2many field channel_ids defined in res.partner: **relation="mail_channel_partner"**

```py
class MyStudent(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"

    mystudent_channel_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='mail_channel_mystudents',
        comodel_name='mail.channel',column1='partner_id', column2='channel_id', 
    )
```

Just as information : the already existing many2many fields is located in the official module : addons/mail/models/res_partner.py

```py
class Partner(models.Model):
    _name = "res.partner"
    _inherit = ['res.partner', 'mail.activity.mixin', 'mail.thread.blacklist']

    channel_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.channel', 'mail_channel_partner', 'partner_id', 'channel_id', string='Channels', copy=False)
```